# NodeJS PTY timing commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, pty

I'm trying to use a node process to kick off an interactive docker session then automate some commands to it:

```js
var spawn = require('pty.js').spawn;

var proc = spawn('docker', [ 'run', '-i', '-t', 'mycontainer' ], {
  name: 'test',
  rows: 30,
  cols: 200,
  cwd: process.env.HOME,
  env: process.env
});

proc.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});

proc.write('cd /tmp');
proc.write('nvm install 0.10\r');
proc.write('npm install');
```

This seems to work, the only issue is it seems like it's just writing in all the commands and firing them. I don't seem to have any control over catching the output or errors of individual commands.

I'm curious if there's a better way to approach this?

Comment: sorry, it's `proc`, I just mistyped.

Comment: If you don't mind doing this in another language the traditional way of handling this is to use expect which is based on tcl (you'll be programming in tcl but expect is written in C)

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe streams to this process, however it is not advised to do so.

```js
const { pipeline } = require('stream');
const { spawn } = require('node-pty')

const proc = spawn('docker', ['run', '--rm', '-ti', 'alpine', '/bin/sh'], {
  name: 'xterm-color',
  cwd: process.env.HOME,
  env: process.env,
  encoding: null,
});

pipeline(process.stdin, proc, (err) => err && console.warn(err.message))
pipeline(proc, process.stdout, (err) => err && console.warn(err.message))
```

The [maintainer have suggested](https://github.com/microsoft/node-pty/issues/409#event-3373779930) to not use pty in like a stream. It's simply a matter of changing the pipeline for something like this.

```js
(async (stream) => {
  for await (const chunk of stream) {
    proc.write(chunk.toString())
  }
})(process.stdin).catch(console.warn)
```

The gist is that we should pass string into the write function. We also should expect string as its output. Therefore, we should not set any encoding in the object so that it by default outputs utf8 string.

Regarding your initial question. `proc.write('ls\r')` is the correct way of doing it. Note the trailing `\r` to virtually press enter. Just like in a normal terminal, when you execute a command, you cannot fire a second one simultaneously. The commands will just queue up and run one after another.

Input:

```js
const { spawn } = require('node-pty')

const proc = spawn('docker', ['run', '--rm', '-ti', '--network=host', 'node', '/bin/sh'], {
  name: 'xterm-color',
  cwd: process.env.HOME,
  env: process.env,
});

proc.write('npm init -y\r')
proc.write('npm i eslint\r')
proc.write('ls node_modules /\r')

const disposable = proc.onData((text) => process.stdout.write(text))

const exitDisposable = proc.onExit(() => {
  disposable.dispose()
  exitDisposable.dispose()
})
```

Output:

```sh
npm i eslint
ls node_modules /
# Wrote to /package.json:

{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}


npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN @1.0.0 No description
npm WARN @1.0.0 No repository field.

+ eslint@7.1.0
added 136 packages from 82 contributors and audited 136 packages in 9.461s

9 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

# /:
bin   etc   lib64  node_modules       package.json  run   sys  var
boot  home  media  opt                proc          sbin  tmp
dev   lib   mnt    package-lock.json  root          srv   usr

node_modules:
@babel                      is-extglob
@types                      is-fullwidth-code-point
...
...
#
```

You see it wrote ls before npm install was completed but it ran afterwards.

Also note that I used `-ti` instead of just `-t` for the docker args.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the source for the `pty.js` module, it is clear that your `proc.write` is really the standard Node `net.Socket.write` -- https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_write_data_encoding_callback

In short, yes, you are just spamming the commands to the socket. You need to wait for each command to finish before executing the next. Thus, you'll need to use the callback parameter of `.write` to determine when a command has finished and then proceed from there. Something like this may work:

```
// this is a quick and dirty hack
let cmdcount = 0;

function submitcmd() {
  switch (cmdcount) {
    case 0:
      proc.write('nvm install 0.10\r', 'utf8', submitcmd);
      break;
    case 1:
      proc.write('npm install', 'utf8', submitcmd);
      break;
  }

  cmdcount += 1;
}

proc.write('cd /tmp', 'utf8', submitcmd);
```

Comment: What I'd really do is wrap the `proc.write` function in such a way that I could use the `Promise` API to simply chain the commands I want to issue.

Comment: I've got that in there but it's only firing the first command, like it's not even hitting the callback.

Comment: I changed it to use `proc.socket.write()` which now fires through the commands, though it still shows them all up front like it's just moving right  through everything

Comment: You may find it easier to just spawn the process yourself instead of going through that pty library -- https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Comment: Know of any good examples of piping in stdin from a spawned proc?

Comment: Looks the best bet would be to supply a writable stream when creating the spawn. You'd then use that stream to send your commands. I'd also include a readable stream for stdout so you can process results.